# Can't alias URLs on apache 2.4

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4

I'm basically trying to redirect `localhost` to `localhost/index.html`. I've tried reverse proxies and using aliases, but neither work:

`ProxyPass "/" "/index.html"` returns an error saying the path has to be absolute, so I tried `ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost/index.html"`, as well as replacing `localhost` with my internal IP, but both result in the webpage perpetually loading.

`Alias "/" "/index.html"` gives a 403 error when trying to access `localhost` and `localhost/index.html`. If I don't use an alias or anything, I can access `localhost/index.html` just fine, which leads me to think that the alias isn't redirecting to where I want it, but I can't figure out where it's redirecting to. The directories section of my `apache2.conf` is as follows:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/mundane.tk/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also have this in my `000-default.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mundane.tk/public_html/

<Directory /var/www/mundane.tk/public_html/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have tried moving my html to the default `/var/www/html/` folder but that gave the exact same problems. I've given directory ownership to the `public_html/` folder and all its sub-directories to apache's group and user, `www-data`.

I'm a huge novice when it comes to apache so I'm probably missing something blindingly obvious; my apologies if that's the case.

Comment: What you are looking for is a RedirectPermanent directive.

Comment: @Capsule just tried that; I'm probably getting the formatting wrong but now it redirects from `localhost` to `localhost/index.htmlindex.htmlindex.html...`.

Comment: The issue is / IS index.html. I don't even understand why you;re trying to do that expect making the URL uglier

Comment: Yeah I know it's meant to be, but it's not behaving like that: I have to navigate to `localhost/index.html` to get my index page. I expect this is something to do with how my virtual hosts are set up or something but I genuinely have no idea. I know I had this working before, but my `modules` folder randomly disappeared so I had to reinstall and now it doesn't work.

Comment: If you have another `index.htm` or `index.php` file in the root folder, then it could potentially pick it up first, depending on the DirectoryIndex directive order. This is what you need to fix instead of hacking stuff fro the get go. Less is more.

Comment: I certainly do not. I'm not "hacking it from the get go", I set everything up the exact same as it was previous to me having to reinstall, but this time `locahost` just returned an error saying that there was no page at that URL.

Comment: So, redirecting `/` to `index.html` because it doesn't naturally deliver it is not a hack? Oh well.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you; like I said I'm a novice. I just want to know why this isn't working any more, and how I can fix it.

Comment: Like I said, check your `DirectoryIndex` directives. If you only have, let's say `index.htm` or `index.php` then your `index.html` file won't be delivered when reaching `/`. Although you'd normally get a 403 and not a 404 if that was the case (you're talking about mundane.tk, right?). Still worth checking what's going on there.